# Best professional/programming 27" 4K monitor for eye strain regardless of price (up to $4000)

Tags: monitors, 4k

I am a researcher in computer science and unfortunately I became extremely sensitive to eye strain over the last few years. I am currently looking for the best available monitor (almost) regardless to the price (let's say up to $4000). I am mostly doing programming (night mode (text on a black background)) and reading scientific papers (text and figures on white background).

Here is what I am looking for:

- Professional type of screen with a max budget at $4000 (but it's fine if the price is $400)
- 27 inches
- 4K (3840x2160)
- TÜV certification (flicker-free, low blue light...)
- Anti-glare
- (and anything that would help reduce eye strain, like panel homogeneity I guess)

Use cases:

- Programming in night mode (text on a black background)
- Reading scientific papers (text and figures on white background)
- Zoom calls/video

Comment: With that price range I think you should consider the new 27" OLED displays that are coming out. They inherently do not have flicker. Blue light might be a concern but changing color settings on the monitor can meaningfully adjust the blue light output (they're self-lit blue subpixels). OLED has fantastic contrast and the ability to emit very low levels of light if that's necessary.